# I want to rename a table by using EF 6 Code First approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

Hi I have an Entity as below:

```
public class Complaint
{
    public Complaint()
    { }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_UniqueConstraintComplaint", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int? InspectionRequestId { get; set; }
    public InspectionRequest InspectionRequest { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_UniqueConstraintComplaint", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public int? InspectionResultId { get; set; }
    public InspectionResult InspectionResult { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_UniqueConstraintComplaint", 3, IsUnique = true)]
    public int? CaseId { get; set; }
    public Case Case { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_UniqueConstraintComplaint", 4, IsUnique = true)]
    public string ComplaintId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to rename this entity as below with couple of column names changed, can somebody please help me in this

```
public class RequestResultCaseComplaint
    {
        public RequestResultCaseComplaint()
        { }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int RequestResultCaseComplaintId { get; set; }        

        [Index("IX_UniqueConstraintComplaint", 1, IsUnique = true)]
        public int? InspectionRequestId { get; set; }
        public InspectionRequest InspectionRequest { get; set; }

        [Index("IX_UniqueConstraintComplaint", 2, IsUnique = true)]
        public int? InspectionResultId { get; set; }
        public InspectionResult InspectionResult { get; set; }

        [Index("IX_UniqueConstraintComplaint", 3, IsUnique = true)]
        public int? CaseId { get; set; }
        public Case Case { get; set; }

        [Index("IX_UniqueConstraintComplaint", 4, IsUnique = true)]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string ComplaintId { get; set; }
    }
```

I previously had the entity as in the 2nd case, unfortunately I removed it, and now when I am trying to create with same name again, whether EF has cached it I don't know, but EF is not recognizing it, can somebody please help me in this, does EF cache the already created Entities with same names, how can we clean it?
Its not allowing me to create the same Entity again even after deleting the Entity and trying regenerate again.

Or at least can I rename already existing Entity and its columns, how can I do it any help please?

Comment: Can you show your DbContext class?

Comment: I could able to complete it, thanks for your help buddy

Comment: @AbdulAleem if you managed to solve your problem then please consider posting the solution as an answer to this question and accepting it (clicking the tick mark sign) so that others know that it has been solved and future readers can be benefited by that information.